# How to move observable outside of ngOnInit() **Updated**

Tags: angular

I have the following simple single component app:

**nav.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav',
  templateUrl: './nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav.component.css']
})
export class NavComponent implements OnInit {
  //vars
  url = 'api address';
  menus;
  content;
  id;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getMenus().subscribe(res => {this.menus = res});
  }  
  //this gets the data for the menus
  getMenus(){
      return this.http.get(this.url);
  }
  //this get the data for the content
  public getContent(): void {
   this.http.get(this.url).subscribe((res) => {this.content = res[this.id]}
 );
  }
  //this gets an id from each menu link, assigns the id to this.id and logs the new value of id.
  public get_id(id)
  {
    this.id = id;
    console.log(id)
    this.getContent()
    return this.id
  }
  }
```

**nav.component.html**

```
//menus
<div *ngFor="let menu of menus; index as id">
    <ul>
        <li><button (click)="get_id(id)">{{menu['course-lesson-name']}}</button></li>
    </ul>
</div>

//content
<div>
    <p *ngIf="content">{{content['course-name']}}</p>
</div>
```

Here is the issue:

nav.component.ts loads a menu and content from functions making API calls and subscribes each using these two observables:

```
    this.getMenus().subscribe(res => {this.menus = res});
    this.getContent().subscribe((res) => {this.content = res[this.id]}) //<--notice this.id variable
```

A function, get_id(id), grabs an index id number from each menu link using (click) and is supposed to value the this.id variable.

I need a way to run the following each time each button is clicked and not be included inside of ngOnInit().

```
    this.getContent().subscribe((res) => {this.content = res[this.id]})
```

Currently, this.getContent() is loading once (because it is in ngOnInit) and will not reload when the new this.id value is passed to it. **It needs to run each time get_id(id) is also run so the new value of id will be passed to it and the correct content will be displayed.**

Currently, all that is happening is the relative id is getting logged to the console each time a button is clicked.

Comment: Why can't you add the code you need to run inside the `(click)` handling function?

Answer (score 0):

First, be aware that in ngOnInit `this.id` is not defined.

Then, keep it simple, if you want `this.getContent` to be called every time a click is made, you can add a call at the end of the `this.getId` function as you are calling it at every click.

Also, you can simplify the observable call doing it in the function itself as you are using component's variable to keep the internal state of `content` and `id`.

```
 public getContent(): void
 {
   this.http.get(this.url).subscribe(
      (res) => {this.content = res[this.id]}
   );
 }

 public get_id(id): int
 {
    this.id = id;
    console.log(id)
    this.getContent(); 
    return this.id
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for this; Ive updated my code with your revisions, but Im still only getting the id being logged to the console on each click. No content (outside of the menu) is showing

Comment: Did you print the `res[this.id]`? If it contains what you are expecting, the view should update automatically.